# Share video on facebook with custom message using jssdk version 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post photo/video on facebook wall using me/photos and me/videos/ method, which requires publish_actions ,user_photos and user_videos extended permissions. I submitted my app for Facebook review for approving extended permissions. I got reply saying that "People must enter all content in the user message field. Your app can't auto-populate the message field with any content, including links and hashtags, even if you allow users to edit the content before sharing."

As per the review feedback I have to allow user to edit the p refilled messages, The method I am using not showing share pop up to edit. Please guide me how to open facebook share pop up to edit the content.. Thanks in advance !!

FB.api('/me/photos?access_token='+accessToken, 'post', { url: fileUrl, 'message':description,access_token: accessToken }, function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                console.log("error occured");
               // alert('Error occured: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));

```
            } else {

            alert("Successfully posted on facebook");
               // $("#status").html("Successfully posted on facebook");
            }
        });
```